# Kafka : Reset offset of a specific partition of topic

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to reset offset of a specific partition of a kafka topic but i did not find any command.

I was
 able to reset offset of all the partition of a topic using the below command but i want to reset offset only for a specific partitions.

Command which worked for all partitions

```
kafka-consumer-groups.sh -- bootstap-server localhost:1111 -- command-config <file> -- group <group> -- topic <topic> -- reset-offset -- shift-by -1
```

The above command doesnt accept partition, and resets for all partitions. How can i reset only specific partition.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To change offset only for a particular partition, you have to pass with `--topic` flag, topic name and partition number that you would like to modify.

Following command can be used:

```
./bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:1111 --group grId --topic someTopicName:0 --reset-offsets --shift-by 1 --execute
```

A summary from `kafka-consumer.groups.sh` may help you understand it better:

> **--topic** : The topic whose consumer group
>   information should be deleted or
>   topic whose should be included in
>   the reset offset process. In `reset-offsets` case, partitions can be
>   specified using this format: `topic1:0,1,2`, where 0,1,2 are the
>   partition to be included in the process. Reset-offsets also supports
>    multiple topic inputs.

Comment: Thanks so much, looking for this only