# How to reset source connector offsets in Apache Kafka-Connect server

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

After deleting the source connector from Kafka connect, saved offsets for this connector are still present in the Kafka.
When the same connector with the same name is started again then it starts to process data from the last saved offset.
Changing the name of the connector is not a solution since it makes hard to automate connector submission.

Is there a workaround for this problem (renaming the source connector is not an options)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consume the offsets topic used by Connect; it is JSON, so you can inspect its format.

Construct a series of messages that set the offset to 0 for the source

For a full example using the FileStreamSource, [see this post](https://rmoff.net/2019/08/15/reset-kafka-connect-source-connector-offsets/)

There is a [KIP-199](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-199%3A+Add+Kafka+Connect+offset+tool) and JIRAs as well that have been asking for tooling around this, also asking that deleting a source connector should delete its offsets.

Answer (score 0):

With version 3.6.0, Kafka Connect will add native support for resetting the offsets of both sink and source connectors via the REST API as part of [KIP-875](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-875%3A+First-class+offsets+support+in+Kafka+Connect).

If you are running version 3.6.0 or later, first issue a PUT request to the `/connectors/{name}/stop` endpoint to stop (but not delete) the connector, then reset its offsets by issuing a DELETE request to the `/connectors/{name}/offsets` endpoint.

Answer (score -2):

what I found is that if you know the topic that the Kafka Connector is using, this might work: [Kafka : Reset offset of a specific partition of topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54889685/kafka-reset-offset-of-a-specific-partition-of-topic) and here's another reference that might help: https://gist.github.com/marwei/cd40657c481f94ebe273ecc16601674b

I think I have had a similar issue and what I did was delete the topics that started with offset, which meant that I had to stop Kafka Connect, delete the applicable offset topics, and then restart Kafka Connect. Not sure if that's the best option, but here are some options for your request.

Comment: I know the topic where offsets are stored, but I cannot reset it to 0 because this would affect all connectors on the Kafka Connect server because all connector offsets are written to the same topic.

Comment: @denisvlah Connectors are keyed by name in that topic, so changing one would not change them all

Comment: In any case, as commented on other answer, source connectors do not use consumer groups so those `kafka-consumer-group` commands wont work

Comment: @denisvlah - On which topic the kafka sink connectors are written the offsets to? thanks

Comment: @denisvlah and how  you manage to overcome this issue?

Answer (score -2):

Reset the offset for the consumer group for the kafka-connect connector. The consumer group for all connectors are different - so it should be okay and not affect any other connectors.

Comment: Source connectors dont use consumer groups

Comment: Oh yeah sorry - i think I read it wrong. You are correct.